# Ada - Column Matrix from 2D array type

Tags: ada

I'm new to Ada. I try to initialize the 2D array that have 2x1 dimension. But I don't know how to do this, if I do something like 1..1 I will get an error.

```
    type Matrix is array(Integer range <>, Integer range <>) of Integer;

    V : Matrix(1..2, 1..3) := (
         (1, 4, 5),
         (2, 5, 3)
    );

    -- Here is my problem !
    U : Matrix(1..2, ???) := ( 
         (1),
         (1)
    );
```

Comment: Which error do you get? My guess is that `1..1` is not the problem, but rather `(1)`, which should then be `(1 => 1)`

Comment: wow thank you very much ! it solved now !

Comment: Explanation: `(1)` could be either a parenthesized expression, or an aggregrate of one value. The language defines it to be an expression; an aggregate of one value *must* use named notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution,

```
    U : Matrix(1..2, 1..1) := (
        (1 => 1),
        (1 => 1)
    );
```

Comment: You can also use U : Matrix(1..2, 1..1)  := (Others => (Others => 1));